# Are messages on parachains buffered on the network differently than they are in standalone environments?

Tags: parachain, networking

We are adding custom networking/gossip logic to our codebase to handle other off-chain protocols over the gossip network. We experience reliability issues in the parachain environment that are both hard to reproduce and which do not occur in the standalone environment.

Is there information or guidance on building networking apps in a parachain context? Are there issues that we should be aware of (such as message buffering, limits, other side-effects that could be possible)?

Comment: What do you mean by parachain environment? And what kind of issues? Can you be please more precise on what is your problem, otherwise no one will be able to help you.